# Is there a Google My Activity equivalent for Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Does Microsoft store browsing history somewhere like Google does?

Comment: My Activity is an aggregate history for an account across all Google apps and services. Individual Microsoft apps or services have their own histories, but I do not believe they have an aggregate panel like Google does. Please note that this topic is NOT on topic for Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Head to [microsoft.com/privacy - dashboard](https://account.microsoft.com/privacy)

[image]

[image]

[image]